# Inner Join with Sum Aggregate function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sum, aggregate-functions, inner-join

I have three tables StockSummary, Item, ItemSpecification.
Here I want to join these three tables and to get Sum(StockSummary.Quantity).
The main Columns are as follows:

```
TableA: StockSummary(ItemID, Quantity)
TableB: Item(ItemID, ItemName, SpecificationID)
TableC: ItemSpecification(SpecificationName, SpecificationID)
```

The desired result should give ItemName, SpecificationName and SUM(Quantity). How to use Aggregate function in Inner Joins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aggregate the desired column & group by the remainder, the fact that the columns are from the result of a join is not relevant in your case;

```
select
   b.ItemName,
   c.SpecificationName,
   sum(a.Quantity)
from
   tablea a
   inner join tableb b on b.ItemID = a.ItemID
   inner join tablec c on c.SpecificationID = b.SpecificationID
group by
   b.ItemName,
   c.SpecificationName
```